# Javascript working in Chrome but not in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm new to javascript. I have an input box that only accepts numbers. If someone copy-paste on that input, it should trim all the non numeric characters. The input field should only be max 10 characters.

Here is the code. It is working in Chrome but not in IE. Can someone figure out what is wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" maxlength="10" title="Number" pattern="[0-9]*" onkeypress='validate(event)' onpaste="strip(this, event)"/>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
        function strip(obj, evt) {
            var theEvent = evt || window.event;
            obj.value = theEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text').replace(/\D/g, '');
obj.value = obj.value.substring(0,Math.min(10,obj.value.length));
            theEvent.returnValue = false;
        }

        function validate(evt) {
            var theEvent = evt || window.event;
            var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
            key = String.fromCharCode(key);
            var regex = /[0-9]/;
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                theEvent.returnValue = false;
                if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
            }
        }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Chrome Version - Version 40.0.2214.115 m
IE Version - 9.0.8

Comment: Any errors or warning appear on IE?

Comment: i run code snippet in IE8-9 and working fine

Comment: ``onpaste`` is a non-standard on not recommended for use. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste. This is straight from MDN: ``Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.``

Comment: @Jeff You should make your comment an answer so I can vote on it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replacing your strip function with the following works:

```
function strip(input, evt) {
    var clipboardData = window.clipboardData ? window.clipboardData : evt.clipboardData;
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var text = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    var processedText = text.replace(/\D/g, '').substring(0, Math.min(10, text.length));
    input.value = processedText;
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I just tested this on Firefox 25.0 and the backspace, delete, home and end  keys do not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are using attribute [pattern](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) which is new attribute in HTML5 and is not supported by IE below version 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a input with type number instead to prevent insertion of characters other than numbers.
However this input type is relatively new and will not work on some older browsers.

Small example:

```
<form>This will allow anything.
<input type="text">
<br />This will allow only numbers.
<input type="number">
<br />Try typing in letters in the bottom box and pressing send.
<br />
<input type="submit">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yqdsaf3t/

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number